# Propertys of Object's type "id"

Tags: ios, object, nsmutablearray, properties

I would bet this is a very basic question, but i don't get it!

I load some REST Data and put it in Objects in a NSMutableArray.

1. Load REST-Data
2. Parsing the Rest-Data to Objects
3. Add the Objects to a NSMutable Array

now i need to access some properties of the objects stored in the mutable array and i get Xcode errors, stating that there is no property with the given name in object of type "id".

Could somebody give me a quick hint? I thought i could use the Objects and their properties within the NSMutable Array directly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to cast the objects in your mutable array, and not use the dot notation. As in

```
[anArray objectAtIndex:i].yourProperty; // will give you an error
[(YourClass*)[anArray objectAtIndex:i] yourProperty]; // should work
```

Comment: Is there a way to do accomplish this without casting? (a little late to the party)

Comment: I think you'll either get a compiler warning saying that the object might not respond to the selector, or an error (no visible interface...). Don't know how would you solve it without casting.